# why to we need a service locator like get_it when we can use Singleton class in Flutter

Tags: flutter, singleton, flutter-dependencies, get-it

For creating API repository, DioClient, Database access class in flutter, we can use singleton pattern and create singleton classes. Then, what is the advantage of using service locators like `get_it`.

Answer (score 1):

True, we may not always need it. If you understand how get_it works, you can do some of the simplest things yourself. But it has proven useful because it further provides functionalities that a simple singleton alone may not suffice.

As much as I would love to explain, someone else has taken out time to do this, here is a link

https://medium.com/flutter-community/how-the-getit-service-locator-package-works-in-dart-fc16a2998c07

Hope it is helpful

Comment: Thanks for the article,  but it can be fully read only on premium plan.